# Two polygons SDO_OVERLAPS, but their intersection is a LINESTRING

Tags: oracle-spatial

A have a problem similar to [Why does st_intersection return non-polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63452951/why-does-st-intersection-return-non-polygons), but this time in Oracle. SDO_OVERLAPS is true for two polygons, and SDO_GEOM.RELATE with the mask 'determine' says OVERLAPBDYINTERSECT. However, SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION returns a LINESTRING. I do understand, that SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION returns a LINESTRING, since inspecting the geometries I would think, that the geometries share just a border. So what I do not understand is, why do SDO_OVERLAPS and SDO_GEOM.RELATE report, that these polygons overlap?

My polygons are in SRID 25832 as given below.

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((698985.94 6167518.54, 698978.2 6167472.42, 698978.74 6167454.55, 698977.43 6167449.98, 698976.25 6167445.86, 698970.71 6167437.43, 698963.2 6167429.88, 698960.01 6167426.67, 698958.43 6167424.83, 698937.66 6167400.72, 698925.43 6167386.53, 698901.71 6167353.91, 698876.51 6167313.75, 698864.62 6167296.17, 698847.52 6167262.63, 698836.1 6167235.78, 698834.09 6167231.54, 698826.83 6167216.93, 698824.31 6167204.35, 698822.09 6167204.79, 698808.74 6167178.12, 698806.88 6167169.49, 698798.62 6167161.68, 698782.01 6167136.17, 698770.26 6167115.94, 698754.86 6167084.58, 698724.06 6167009.8, 698721.4 6166987.42, 698692.78 6166929.5, 698648.77 6166845.25, 698636.84 6166822.99, 698629.96 6166814.59, 698619.09 6166797.03, 698609.01 6166784.5, 698582.8 6166742.11, 698565.32 6166714.01, 698550.41 6166689.13, 698529.58 6166655.42, 698527.57 6166652.09, 698512.71 6166627.51, 698502.06 6166609.94, 698498.12 6166603.44, 698496.02 6166599.54, 698474.11 6166558.43, 698464.19 6166532.15, 698452.26 6166513.57, 698447.31 6166499.65, 698437.18 6166479.95, 698402.34 6166402.32, 698382.89 6166357.8, 698375.94 6166341.89, 698367.26 6166320.78, 698366.14 6166317.49, 698334.96 6166246.45, 698336.52 6166244.08, 698329.46 6166226.47, 698321.69 6166184.66, 698311.16 6166131.38, 698307.04 6166112.13, 698262.27 6166121.6, 698219.7 6166132.92, 698214.96 6166132.79, 698142.06 6166240.41, 697976.28 6166329.01, 697862.56 6166426.6, 697675.81 6166308.88, 697303.27 6166612.66, 697101.35 6166523.15, 696776.36 6166716.02, 696747.15 6167047.53, 696553.17 6167180.09, 696527.43 6167279.09, 696453.09 6167430.1, 696345.66 6167515.84, 696321.87 6167633.86, 696322.4 6167638.1, 696432.67 6167967.62, 696385.59 6168080.19, 696337.13 6168099.34, 696094.03 6168225.88, 696086.71 6168295.21, 696085.15 6168314.16, 696085.43 6168370.63, 696089.78 6168433.68, 696104.64 6168520.24, 696098.03 6168583.63, 696059.2 6168685.38, 696073.22 6168764.87, 696088.29 6168826.75, 696034.77 6168985.87, 696019.17 6169042.41, 696012.68 6169074.01, 696010.52 6169088.54, 696004.15 6169144.98, 696002.99 6169183.19, 696001.11 6169187.42, 696001.09 6169187.61, 696002.51 6169215.68, 696007.49 6169260.16, 696023.51 6169331.44, 696043.72 6169390.49, 696049.35 6169401.04, 696052.37 6169510.44, 696056.9 6169545.27, 696060.89 6169562.31, 696106.23 6169711.22, 696111.9 6169715.05, 696123.25 6169721.92, 696215.1 6169769.11, 696229.15 6169783.47, 696222.32 6169822.4, 696236.31 6170319.56, 696311.79 6170052.04, 696469.64 6170097.76, 696551.94 6170099.86, 696794.59 6170471.48, 696773.92 6169987.3, 696841.34 6170010.16, 696841.57 6170011.66, 697203.92 6170383.95, 697146.89 6170429.24, 697138.09 6170527.67, 697143.64 6170544.57, 697205.27 6170655.09, 697267.85 6170660.89, 697406.83 6170589.4, 697408.22 6170588.45, 697459.48 6170608.72, 697462.17 6170618.31, 697530.28 6170771.27, 697596.32 6170793.69, 697649.75 6170787.81, 697782.33 6170585.87, 697879.05 6170599.47, 697887.14 6170674.72, 697921.38 6170770.16, 697893.45 6170873.79, 697959.64 6171001.48, 697989.84 6171028.99, 697999.66 6171033.08, 698088.67 6170902.76, 698236.63 6170869.46, 698243.46 6170864.86, 698289.0 6170811.92, 698116.13 6170448.1, 698200.82 6170258.79, 698179.34 6170071.72, 698247.03 6169996.46, 698291.83 6169985.75, 698432.68 6169915.71, 698680.58 6169922.66, 698721.72 6169867.81, 698721.42 6169860.31, 698720.69 6169854.74, 698720.33 6169851.99, 698740.43 6169854.23, 698742.24 6169854.41, 698743.81 6169854.6, 698791.12 6169859.88, 698826.28 6169863.78, 698868.54 6169868.54, 698875.93 6169869.36, 699008.5 6169884.26, 699045.27 6169887.82, 699068.48 6169889.39, 699088.31 6169890.73, 699093.68 6169891.09, 699094.71 6169891.16, 699123.65 6169893.11, 699125.29 6169893.22, 699126.99 6169893.17, 699181.52 6169897.02, 699204.3 6169899.47, 699255.56 6169905.6, 699289.67 6169909.67, 699324.6 6169914.16, 699335.29 6169915.56, 699335.7 6169905.1, 699336.02 6169897.09, 699336.11 6169895.01, 699336.3 6169890.27, 699334.28 6169874.83, 699334.14 6169874.14, 699329.23 6169849.64, 699329.59 6169822.75, 699329.79 6169807.12, 699329.85 6169803.23, 699329.88 6169801.25, 699329.94 6169796.23, 699329.98 6169793.76, 699330.0 6169792.03, 699330.12 6169787.99, 699330.68 6169769.02, 699331.99 6169725.05, 699336.61 6169692.44, 699336.32 6169687.55, 699335.37 6169683.86, 699335.11 6169682.86, 699332.42 6169678.61, 699328.48 6169672.67, 699320.16 6169660.11, 699317.72 6169655.56, 699316.59 6169652.64, 699314.99 6169646.83, 699314.62 6169644.71, 699314.19 6169642.3, 699313.71 6169636.74, 699313.49 6169634.26, 699309.86 6169598.24, 699305.74 6169522.7, 699304.3 6169499.73, 699301.41 6169447.28, 699296.86 6169363.61, 699289.64 6169260.48, 699284.83 6169191.68, 699284.35 6169173.03, 699284.4 6169144.27, 699281.69 6169120.86, 699279.33 6169101.53, 699278.29 6169086.94, 699279.31 6169070.6, 699279.14 6169060.18, 699277.71 6169039.74, 699276.91 6169021.39, 699275.3 6169007.58, 699275.83 6168990.67, 699276.67 6168979.56, 699280.21 6168964.98, 699281.24 6168953.75, 699274.9 6168897.39, 699272.26 6168864.96, 699271.52 6168858.07, 699268.72 6168832.32, 699266.37 6168823.64, 699250.35 6168676.57, 699234.82 6168518.09, 699226.63 6168480.66, 699224.93 6168472.45, 699220.45 6168450.73, 699220.28 6168449.92, 699219.9 6168448.06, 699219.39 6168445.55, 699215.25 6168425.39, 699213.82 6168413.17, 699212.55 6168412.58, 699208.28 6168391.57, 699203.94 6168377.51, 699199.7 6168360.09, 699194.23 6168333.97, 699194.0 6168332.84, 699193.54 6168330.66, 699192.07 6168323.67, 699190.56 6168315.78, 699188.33 6168305.18, 699187.6 6168304.06, 699187.42 6168303.1, 699186.1 6168292.65, 699185.84 6168291.13, 699185.25 6168287.68, 699183.01 6168276.3, 699182.66 6168274.49, 699181.55 6168274.95, 699175.09 6168229.9, 699163.01 6168232.46, 699158.27 6168206.8, 699159.11 6168196.53, 699161.97 6168186.54, 699167.6 6168175.56, 699169.79 6168168.02, 699169.37 6168166.76, 699163.53 6168149.28, 699158.17 6168133.49, 699153.34 6168121.34, 699151.33 6168115.3, 699139.83 6168087.47, 699123.85 6168033.17, 699101.07 6167955.76, 699096.63 6167939.43, 699074.87 6167859.57, 699065.9 6167826.42, 699059.93 6167804.75, 699058.44 6167799.3, 699050.59 6167770.45, 699043.96 6167728.54, 699031.13 6167674.83, 699030.41 6167671.02, 699025.31 6167644.04, 699023.61 6167636.66, 699019.52 6167621.72, 699015.08 6167609.24, 699011.76 6167599.93, 699002.58 6167580.05, 698998.71 6167568.98, 698992.52 6167540.98, 698987.17 6167524.74, 698985.94 6167518.54)))

MULTIPOLYGON (((695804.47 6166608.43, 695737.37 6166980.94, 695667.03 6167012.02, 695477.06 6167082.19, 695387.32 6167013.26, 695329.91 6166957.31, 695302.89 6166906.19, 695298.16 6166845.2, 695344.14 6166774.84, 695435.94 6166712.73, 695439.25 6166711.41, 695804.47 6166608.43)), ((698214.96 6166132.79, 698142.06 6166240.41, 697976.28 6166329.01, 697862.56 6166426.6, 697675.81 6166308.88, 697303.27 6166612.66, 697101.35 6166523.15, 696776.36 6166716.02, 696399.06 6166351.69, 696246.01 6166357.98, 695936.74 6166566.48, 695865.41 6166582.86, 695806.11 6166605.23, 695769.44 6166571.02, 695614.94 6166399.72, 695601.96 6166388.53, 695173.07 6166138.52, 695148.45 6166125.48, 695002.23 6166165.04, 694625.56 6165748.37, 694611.16 6165610.52, 694612.69 6165604.06, 694695.6 6165479.55, 694595.06 6165098.14, 694636.06 6164905.24, 694691.39 6164696.75, 694790.68 6164611.75, 695048.64 6164570.2, 695445.27 6164901.75, 695568.87 6164904.53, 696052.95 6165108.51, 696070.37 6165162.19, 696247.21 6165374.81, 696339.18 6165415.3, 696520.44 6165404.71, 696570.74 6165413.38, 696730.68 6165488.0, 696850.75 6165588.44, 696892.21 6165635.71, 697083.46 6165682.7, 697097.91 6165684.09, 697103.35 6165686.31, 697128.44 6165683.68, 697198.23 6165629.82, 697278.74 6165592.65, 697334.45 6165575.89, 697374.71 6165571.04, 697376.89 6165571.04, 697452.75 6165554.08, 697492.980000001 6165548.73, 697603.76 6165545.74, 697704.69 6165553.29, 697756.65 6165513.45, 697974.9 6165304.92, 697985.06 6165334.31, 697995.55 6165364.35, 698000.0 6165376.89, 698003.42 6165386.31, 698015.1 6165419.24, 698026.78 6165453.05, 698037.81 6165483.72, 698048.71 6165515.14, 698059.25 6165544.52, 698069.22 6165573.08, 698080.33 6165604.75, 698091.71 6165636.24, 698096.940000001 6165651.0, 698097.58 6165653.73, 698098.0 6165655.84, 698103.25 6165669.46, 698103.28 6165683.2, 698106.66 6165700.72, 698112.980000001 6165736.2, 698122.51 6165787.84, 698135.68 6165861.72, 698145.59 6165919.19, 698144.34 6165928.99, 698158.31 6166000.1, 698166.17 6166043.16, 698176.18 6166088.55, 698186.1 6166139.35, 698186.13 6166139.52, 698214.96 6166132.79)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to one of the polygons having wrong orientation. Appearantly you cannot trust the Oracle spatial operators or functions, when a geometry is registered with a "wrong" orientation. Here a three simple examples showing that:

```
select sdo_geom.relate(sdo_geometry('POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))', 25832), 'determine', sdo_geometry('POLYGON((0 1, 1 1, 1 2, 0 2, 0 1))', 25832), 0.05)
from dual
; -- correct orientation: TOUCH
select sdo_geom.relate(sdo_geometry('POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))', 25832), 'determine', sdo_geometry('POLYGON((0 1, 0 2, 1 2, 1 1, 0 1))', 25832), 0.05)
from dual
; -- both wrong orientation, south-north: COVERS
select sdo_geom.relate(sdo_geometry('POLYGON((0 1, 0 2, 1 2, 1 1, 0 1))', 25832), 'determine', sdo_geometry('POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))', 25832), 0.05)
from dual
; -- both wrong orientation, north-south: OVERLAPBDYINTERSECT
```

I write "wrong" in quotation marks, since in my opinion strictly speaking there is no such thing as a wrong orientation. You could consistently assert, that the interior of a polygon is on the left side of the boundary when travelling in the direction given by the sequence of points. Thus a simple polygon in "wrong" orientation would mean a punched hole in the world. But Oracle seems not to implement the same orientation logic in the RELATE functionality and the INTERSECTION functionality.

Comment: Well, no doubt, oracle spatial has a few peculiarities but it is clearly stated in the manuals that the geometries involved in spatial operators or functions **must** be valid - according to oracle - in a proper tolerance. So, the steps would be 1) determine the meaningful tolerance (usually: max num of  decimals, then down by .05), 2) validate/rectify the geometries to that tolerance and then 3) perform any operations.  Needless to say, if an operation creates a new geometry or alters an existing one, this too should be validated...

Comment: You are right @GregStef. I tried out some spatial operations on geometries with wrong orientation or narrower than the tolerance and observed several inconsistencies between different operations.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable cause for such behavior is poor use of the `tolerance` parameter. According to your ordinates (excluding e.g. 697492.980000001 - a known artifact), the proper `tolerance` is 0.005.
If, as a rough example, your metadata are at 0.000**05** and a node of polygon A is inside polygon B by 0.000**1** `SDO_OVERLAPS` would be `TRUE`. `SDO_GEOM.RELATE(a.geom,'determine',b.geom,TOL)` would output `OBERLAPBDYINTERSECT` for TOL < 0.00005, but the output would change to `TOUCH` for TOL >= 0.00005
Accordingly, `SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION` with an improperly high tolerance would produce a (multi)line, whereas, in the proper tolerance, a (sliver)polygon should be produced.

Comment: Various tolerances were tried with no impact on the result.